# Getting entity with referenced entities in EF

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have an entity called Study:

```
 public class Study
{
    public Study()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string StudyUid { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

I use Unit of work design pattern, I would like to get the study with it's tasks.

I've tried everything.

I've tried this in the repository class:

```
  public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string   
  includePath = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includePath))
        {
            DbSet.Include(includePath);
        }
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }
```

calling it with:

```
 Study study = studyRepository.SearchFor(c => c.StudyUid == 
 studyUid,"Tasks").FirstOrDefault<Study>();
```

I even tried just for the experiment, removing the word virtual in the tasks property.

All result in study.Tasks.Count = 0;

In the Db I can see that there are tasks with the StudyUid that I use.

Please share any insights that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any `.Include()` calls should be added after the query is constructed, otherwise they are ignored. You should write

```
public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string   
includePath = null)
{
    var query = DbSet.Where(predicate);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includePath))
    {
        query = query.Include(includePath);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Your problem is also that you did `DbSet.Include(includePath)` instead of `query = query.Include(includePath)`. `Include()` returns a query you should enumerate. In itself, it doesn't change the query it is called on.